# All optimal solutions of a linear program

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, math-software

Is there a software package that can output *all* optimal solutions of a linear program if there are multiple such solutions?

Comment: What do you mean by "all?" Suppose you have a three-variable problem, your constraints limit you to the cube $0\le x\le 1$, $0\le y\le 1$, $0\le z\le 1$, and the problem is to minimize $x+y$. You have uncountably many optimal solutions, so you can't output all of them.

Comment: i meant all the optimal basic feasible solutions

Comment: Did you check [CPLEX](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/integration/optimization/cplex-optimizer/)?